# How To Disallow URLs in Robots.txt ending with numeric values

Tags: robots.txt

I need help removing or DisAllowing some malicious URLs that Google has configured with my main domain. I didn't really pay attention until my site broke down and I found hundreds of pages like website dot com / 10588msae28bdem12b84

Now I want to Disallow: all of them in Robots.txt

I need your help thanks And I also want to remove them from the Google index. Any excellent advice would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use ten rules with wildcards like this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*0
Disallow: /*1
Disallow: /*2
Disallow: /*3
Disallow: /*4
Disallow: /*5
Disallow: /*6
Disallow: /*7
Disallow: /*8
Disallow: /*9
```

However, this probably not the best solution to your problem.  It is likely that your site was hacked.  You should clean that up by following this guide: [Help, I think I've been hacked!  |  Web Fundamentals  |  Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/hacked)

You need to find a way of removing the hack so that these URLs return a 404 or 410 status code which Google won't index.   Then you should actualy let Google crawl those URLs to know they are gone.